# pdf/handwritten notes with lots of equation to latex CONVERSION

Tags: equations, pdf, conversion

I want to know any way I can convert pdf/handwritten notes with lots of equation to latex. Just want to extract equation  from pdf in latex form ($...$).

Previous answers are very old . any NEW UPDATE ?

Comment: If the PDF uses the experimental accessibility support, you might be able to access it. But that is currently experimental, so unless one of the experimenters produced the PDF, you're out of luck.

Comment: you can not extract something that is not there however mathpix may be able to OCR the formula and derive new latex to make similar output

Comment: To OCR, cut out those equations first and align them, both with a graphics program. // However, the tool of the trade is called "patience", while you recreate the latex document equation by equation by hand ...